# Enormous robots invade Earth through lightning

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I watched a film not longer than 7 years ago. I remember that there was thunder and on the next(?) day enormous robots came out of Earth (they were underground). Later the main character discovered how did the robots got underground - through the lightning. When a lightning bolt struck the robot somehow using the lightning traveled through it (or was in the lightning, I'm not sure) and that way he was not more than 5m underground. The main character was a man with dark hair. I think he had a brown leather jacket though that just might be my imagination. I think the robots were all over the world (i.e. there was thunder everywhere and they were underground all over the world). The robots were making loud noises (lasted about 5s) from time to time.

I remember that the first robot came from underneath the road in the main character's city. People started panicking and running away. I think he told his wife to leave and took only his kid(?).

There was also a scene in which he went (he had a car and drove there) to a yellow big house which was the main character's mother's(?) house. I think his wife was meant to be there. He took some food from the fridge and left.

The next scene I remember is when the main character was running away with his daughter(?) (not from a specific robot, running like from the place where the robot was) and found an old house on a small hill(?). The owner let them inside. He allowed them to stay in the basement. The main character put the daughter to sleep. They woke up in the night hearing a robot (making that loud noise). The robot had some kind of a "hand" which was more like a extendable metal pipe with an eye or some kind of sensor and a light(?) at the end. The robot thoroughly searched the basement with that "hand". He didn't see the main character though and left.

The next scene I remember, which might have been the next one in the film, was the main character with his daughter trying to enter a ship. There was a lot of people there and not all of them managed to get in. Here my memory gets a little blurry. I think the main character managed to get on the ship but I also kind of remember a robot appearing behind a hill to which the ship was going and possibly the people panicking.

After that I only remember the kind of final scene. The main character noticed that the birds can freely fly around a robot (which they previously couldn't as he had some kind of a shield). There were some military and explained (or told to shoot, not sure) the situation to one of the soldiers. They started shooting and the robot fell down. I think they took out a dead or almost dead alien from it (he controlled the robot). All the robots were killed after that.

I just remembered a scene though the memory is blurry and I'm not sure whether it's from that film. I think someone was taken by the robot and inside there were I think 2 cages looking like a ball made of metal bars. The person was somehow rescued.

Comment: I did guess from your description that this might be a film adaption of War of the Worlds, but my, it appears they deviated a heck lot from the original...

Comment: If I google "movie where robots travel through lightning", "movie where robots try to take over", "movie where robots come from storms", etc. the first response is all the 2005 adaptation of War of the Worlds.

Comment: I would just like like to confirm that Google is fantastic when it comes to finding movies from vague descriptions. Indeed, just pasting the title of your post into Google ("Enormous robots invade Earth through lightnings") immediately presents the IMDb page for War of the Worlds as one of the first results.

Comment: @USER_8675309 I never thought google would be good at searching for films and I didn't even try to search for it there. Next time I'll ask google before asking here. Thanks!

Comment: When I read the title, my first thought was "Getter Robo G!?!?!" but then I read the rest and realized it was not that.

Comment: @Mibac no worries, glad you could the movie name

Comment: Damnit, missed my chance to place the same answer on two separate sites: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/125372/21267

Comment: Am I the only one who guessed it right just by reading the title?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[War of the Worlds](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407304/) 2005

> Ray Ferrier (Cruise) is a divorced dockworker and less-than-perfect father. When his ex-wife and her new husband drop off his teenage son Robbie and young daughter Rachel for a rare weekend visit, a strange and powerful lightning storm suddenly touches down. What follows is the extraordinary battle for the future of humankind through the eyes of one American family fighting to survive it in this contemporary retelling of H.G. Wells seminal classic sci-fi thriller.

Comment: FYI The robots didn't travel by lightening. The robots had been on earth since before humans (Original war of the worlds story not sure if it made it to the film). The lightening was some kind of transportation device for the drivers (operators?)

Comment: Yeah, it was already on earth in this version too.

Answer (score 16):

It appears to be [War of the Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Worlds_(2005_film)).

> Unexplained changes in the weather occur, including **lightning that strikes multiple times in the middle of an intersection** and disrupts all electricity.
>
> Ray joins the crowd at the scene of the lightning strikes, and witnesses a massive "Tripod" war machine emerge from the ground and use alien weaponry to disintegrate most of the witnesses, turning them to a grey dust and leaving only their empty clothes behind. **Ray collects his children, steals a car and drives to Mary Ann's home in suburban New Jersey to take refuge. The next morning, he discovers that a Boeing 747 has crashed in the street.** A news team scavenging for food while surveying the wreckage explain that there are multiple Tripods that have attacked major cities including New York City, Paris, Washington, D.C., and London, and have force shields to protect them from human weapons. They also explain that the lightning was how the aliens were able to enter the Tripods. Ray decides to take the kids to Boston to be with their mother. The three are forced to abandon the stolen car after a mob takes it by force. They later survive a Tripod attack which causes a Hudson River ferry to sink. During a desperate battle between U.S. Marines and the aliens, Ray is forced to choose between being separated from Rachel and preventing Robbie from joining the fight; he lets Robbie go with the Marines, who are overwhelmed. While escaping, Ray and Rachel are offered shelter by Harlan Ogilvy, who presumes that the aliens had buried their technology on Earth millions of years ago and has delusions that they can fight against the aliens themselves by observing their operations, as they are right next to their camp.